# How can I customize the slider in the middle of screen

Tags: flutter, slider, slide

i am trying to make a slider in the middle of screen and hide the half of second product.
i want my slider to look like this

[i want my slider to look like this anybody got any idea how to do it ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk7fB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreen(),
    ));

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Horizontal ListView'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 24.0),
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height * 0.35,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: numbers.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .width * 0.6,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Container(
                child: Center(child: Text(numbers[index].toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),)),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might inspire you, [custom listview](https://flutter4fun.com/ui-challenge-2-gaming-app-design-by-nevil-suresh-part-2-2/):

```
class GameModel {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  GameModel({
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
  });
}
final game1 = GameModel(
  image: 'https://img.techpowerup.org/201029/game1.png',
  title: 'Road Fight',
  subtitle: 'Shooting Cars',
);
final game2 = GameModel(
  image: 'https://img.techpowerup.org/201029/game2.png',
  title: 'Vikings',
  subtitle: 'Sons of Ragnar',
);
final List<GameModel> games = [
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
  game1,
  game2,
];
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter 4 Fun'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: HorizontalSnappingList(
          itemWidth: 188.0,
          itemHorizontalMargin: 0,
          itemCount: games.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => GameItemWidget(gameModel: games[i]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```